# Social Engineering Toolkit Errors

Tags: github, penetration-testing

I'm trying to use the Infectious Media Generator to practice some pen-testing with a USB. As I go through the process, after I put the port number I get this:

```
set:payloads> Port to connect back on [443]:443
[-] Generating fileformat exploit...
[*] Payload creation complete.
[*] All payloads get sent to the /root/.set/template.pdf directory


[!] Something went wrong, printing the error: name 'src' is not defined
```

I saw something that said to update, however when I run ./seupdate it erases everything about SET and says it needs a directory to specify where it's pulling information from. I initially tried routing to github but that didn't work.

There is also the issue that the user manual specifies using the ./set-update command however I can't find that executable anywhere in my directory.

I also tried running the command on SET's website to install SET but that didn't work either which is why I downloaded the .zip and extracted it. Anyone run into these errors?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a site for *specific programming questions*. Your question does not appear to be directly about programming, and it lacks necessary information if it were about programming (e.g. instead of "I saw something about update", including the precise message would be more helpful). Try getting in touch with the company behind the product, either via official support channels or by submitting an issue on GitHub.